# How to clear input type=file in modal bootstrap 3 when open it with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal in Bootstrap 3 where I want to get a file from the user. My problem is when the user selects the file but it fails to load and closes the modal and opens it again, the previous file remains.
How can I delete this file in the function that opens the modal with onclick?

```
<button class="pointer" onclick="return contractUpload('${ml.getId()}')"><a>upload contract</a></button>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contractModal">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top: 15%">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">contract modal <span id="mId2"></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">select file :</label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-success">
                                        <input type="file" id="contractFile" accept="application/pdf">
                                        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                                        <span id="browse">choose :</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">upload</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
    function contractUpload(mId) {
        $('#contractModal').modal();
        document.getElementById("mId2").innerHTML = mId;
    }
</script>
```

I used the following code but it doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById("contractFile").value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to reset the value of your `#contractFile` element after the modal is hidden. This can be done by simply [listening to the `hidden.bs.modal` event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#events), i.e.:

```js
const modal = document.getElementById('contractModal')
modal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
  document.getElementById('contractFile').value = '';
});
```

Of course, if you want to reset the input before the modal is fully hidden, then listen to the `hide.bs.modal` instead, even though this will create a strange UI/UX as the field is reset as the modal fades out.

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
const modal = document.getElementById('contractModal')
modal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
  document.getElementById('contractFile').value = '';
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#contractModal">Open modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="contractModal">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top: 15%">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">contract modal <span id="mId2"></span>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">select file :</label>
                <label class="btn btn-success">
                  <input type="file" id="contractFile" accept="application/pdf">
                  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                  <span id="browse">choose :</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">upload</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in the question, I want to do this with the onclick function.

Comment: Then reset the value when the modal is shown by listening to the `show.bs.modal` event

Comment: I can't send ID with `show.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal` events. That's why I used onclick. And these two events do not work in onclick.

Comment: What do you mean you can’t send ID? You don’t need an ID to dispatch the event. The solution is based on precisely the same code you’ve provided.